# JPanel from subclass not adding to driver JFrame correctly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am having some trouble trying to add a JPanel i have created in a subclass to the JFrame i had created in my driver class. Im not sure why but the panel doesnt display how it should and the only way i can get it to work is by defining the JFrame in the subclass and driver class but then i end up with two differnt JFrames, one with the stuff i want on it and a blank one. Any ideas? i had added the code from both classes and also images of how it should look like and what it does look like.

my driver class;

```
public class GUIDriver extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GUIDesign newOrder = new GUIDesign();

    //frame
    JFrame myframe = new JFrame("ROFA: Royal Furniture Ordering System");
    myframe.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    myframe.setVisible(true);
    myframe.setSize(900,600); 
    myframe.setResizable(false);
    myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    myframe.add(newOrder);

}
```

and my GUI class;

```
public class GUIDesign extends JPanel implements ActionListener {




    GUIDesign(){      

    JButton chair = new JButton("Add Chair");
    JButton desk  = new JButton("Add Desk");
    JButton table = new JButton("Add Table");
    JButton clear = new JButton("Clear All");
    JButton save = new JButton("Save file");
    JButton load = new JButton("Load file");


    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel(layout);
    panelLeft.setLayout(layout);
    panelLeft.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.lightGray, Color.black));
    this.add(panelLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);


   GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 0, 1, 1.0, 1.0,
        GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(
              0,0,0,0), 0, 0);

   c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    panelLeft.add(save, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    panelLeft.add(load, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    panelLeft.add(chair, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    panelLeft.add(table, c);


    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 4;
    panelLeft.add(desk, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    panelLeft.add(clear, c);

    }

@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated 
    methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

This is what it is meant to look like:

[image]

and this is what i end up with:

[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a JPanel uses a `FlowLayout`. A `FlowLayout` will display components at their preferred size and the default is for center alignment, which can be changed to left or right.

```
this.add(panelLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

You can't just use a BorderLayout constraint for the FlowLayout when adding the component.

The code should be:

```
this.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
this.add(panelLeft, BorderLayout.LINE_START); // new recommendation instead of using "WEST".
```

This should now align the panel to the left side of the panel.

Also, note that using a `GridLayout` would be easier than using a `GridBagLayout`.

The code for adding the buttons to the panel would simple be:

```
JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );
panelleft.add(save);
panelLeft.add(load);
```

No need for any constraints.

Comment: Thank you so much!